# Gravity forms: checkboxes loaded by AJAX get unchecked on bad validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, checkbox, gravity-forms-plugin

Using Gravity Forms, the checkboxes are loaded by AJAX based on the value of a dropdown. All works fine. However, when the form is submitted and is invalid (eg. 1 required field left empty), all check boxes get unchecked.

I use `$(document).on('gform_post_render', function( ) {}` to re-load the checkboxes again after bad validation.

So the question is, how can I keep the checkboxes that where checked, checked?

I haven't found any example or solution concerning this issues. No errors in the console. Checkboxes loaded by Gravity forms stay checked on bad validation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might care, I ended up with the following solution. The checked / unchecked boxes are stored as a string of 1's and 0's to be retrieved later.

```
$(document).on('change', "input[type='checkbox']", function() {

    var sList = "";

    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {

        var checked = (this.checked ? "1" : "0");

        sList += (sList == "" ? checked : "," + checked);

    });

    localStorage.setItem( 'checkBoxList', sList );

});
```